# sqlcipher stopped working in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, sqlcipher

I have use Sqlite (sqlcipher) in my iOS project for database. In iOS 9 all things are working perfectly. Now i have update new Xcode. But DB encryption is not working now.

```
sqlite3 *db1;
    if (sqlite3_open([[self.databaseURL path] UTF8String], &db1) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char* key = [g_sqlite_key UTF8String];
        AZLog(@"%s",key);
        sqlite3_key(db1, key, (int)strlen(key));
        if (sqlite3_exec(db1, (const char*) "SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master;", NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            AZLog(@"Password is correct, or a new database has been initialized");
        } else {
            AZLog(@"Incorrect password!");
        }
        sqlite3_close(db1);
    }
```

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by not working. Can you explain what is going wrong.

Comment: Write now database is encrypted by using above method, but if i try to perform write operation on database than got error "file is encrypted or is not a database"

Comment: Have you checked the below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide readwrite and open-create permission while encryption of database using sqlcipher.

```
sqlite3 *db1;
    if (sqlite3_open_v2([[self.databaseURL path] UTF8String], &db1, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char* key = [g_sqlite_key UTF8String];
        AZLog(@"%s",key);
        sqlite3_key(db1, key, (int)strlen(key));
        if (sqlite3_exec(db1, (const char*) "SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master;", NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            AZLog(@"Password is correct, or a new database has been initialized");
        } else {
            AZLog(@"Incorrect password!");
        }
        sqlite3_close(db1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There were many changes with Xcode 8 and the new SDKs. Please refer to this guidance:

https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/important-advisory-sqlcipher-with-xcode-8-and-new-sdks/1688